# UITableView never call didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I am using `UITableView` with `Json` parsing.

In the

```
 -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading :(NSURLConnection *) connection{

     self.resultTable.delegate = self;

     self.resultTable.dataSource = self; }
```

I am parsing data and sets the `UITableView's`   `delegate` and `datasource` self.

When i compile that program, data that i parsed with `jSON` coming correctly without any trouble.

The main problem is :  When I try to tap in to table of row, debugger never come to

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I tried lots of thing ( include segue etc.. )  But I cannot choose any cell's row with tapping with my finger. It really feels me  like tapping textfield ...

Anyone know about that issue  ?

Best Regards ...

-Edit-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _userSettings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"CellID";


    ResultNearbyList *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [cell.profilePictureIndicator startAnimating];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[ResultNearbyList alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.userProfilePicture.profileID = [userFBIDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    self.userDOBStr = [userDOB objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    self.userGenderStr = [userGender objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [cell.profilePictureIndicator stopAnimating];

        [_listNearbyView stopAnimating];


        cell.userNickName.text = [userNickNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *fullName = [userFullNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        NSString* fullNameUTF8 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[fullName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        //NSString *fullNameUTF8 = [NSString stringWithCString:[fullName cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


        cell.userFullName.text = fullNameUTF8;

        NSString *userCityCountry = [userCountryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        userCityCountry = [userCityCountry stringByAppendingString:@"/"];

        userCityCountry = [userCityCountry stringByAppendingString:[userCityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        cell.userCityCountry.text = userCityCountry;

        NSString *userDestination = [userDistanceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSRange range = [userDestination rangeOfString:@"."];

        NSString *substring = (range.location != NSNotFound) ? [userDestination substringToIndex:range.location] : nil;

        substring = [substring stringByAppendingString:@" km"];

        if([substring intValue] == 0)
        {
            substring = (range.location != NSNotFound) ? [userDestination substringFromIndex:range.location] : nil;

            substring = [substring substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];

            substring = [substring stringByAppendingString:@" m"];
        }



        cell.userDistance.text = substring;

        return cell; 

}
```

Screen Shot :[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN6rS.png)

Comment: can you show your code for cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: is the cell highlighting when you long press it?

Comment: @micantox , I edited . Wain , Nope . It does not high lighting ...

Comment: is the table definitely getting touch events? i.e. can you scroll it?

Comment: yes sure , I am adding screenshot now .

Comment: what about the disclosure button? Does the accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath method gets called when you click on that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your story board, select UITable and check to see if selection is set to "single Selection". Also note the checkmark "Show selection on touch"

[image]

Comment: It's set single selection and checked for Show Selection on Touch :(

Comment: I tried everything , except handling all data in array after connectionDidFinishLoading and push another viewController. I think using GDC and TableView makes problem. 

Is there any good example for handling NSURLConnection and Tableview in same UIView  ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake. My missing part is , I just add objective-c class file as UIViewController for create  Cell prototype view. Than i changed the UIViewController -> UITableViewCell. But changing manually to class type, did not add the following instances :

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

When i set these instance to my UItableViewCell class implementation file , the problem has fixed :)

Thank you for all your help ...